# android listview onclick opens textfiles in raw folder

Tags: android

I have a listView that I want to display text files in the row folder corresponding to the list item that has been clicked. My code so far:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String displaytxt = "";
            int fileLen = 0;
              try {
                  InputStream text = null;

                  switch(position) {
                  case 1:
                  text = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books1);
                     break;
                  case 2:
                    text = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books2); 
                    break;
                  case 3:
                      text = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books3);
                         break;
                         default:
                             break;
                  }
             fileLen = text.available();
             byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileLen];

             text.read(fileBuffer);
             text.close();
             displaytxt = new String (fileBuffer);

              }
              catch (IOException e) {

              }

              tv.setText(displaytxt);

        }
```

But when I click the first item on the list I get an error in the emulator

Comment: Could you please provide the logcat ?? to be able to help u

Comment: your `text` might be null

Comment: Post your error that you have received..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
switch(position) {
    case 0:
        text = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books1);
        break;
    case 1:
        text = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books2);
        break;
    case 2:
        text = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books3);
        break;
    default:
        text = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.books1); // paste default book
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Putting case 0 first did the trick. But wat if I want to open  the textview in another activity? How do I go about it? I'm just a beginner

Comment: Just pass the values to next activity through the intent, Please check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398668/how-to-pass-listview-selected-item-values-to-another-activity/32398974#32398974