# Display data from database inside ListView

Tags: android, json, database, listview

I have this Activity that get data from a table in my database and I display this data inside a ListView. But the thing is that I want to make clickable the itens inside this ListView and once the user clicks on an item it should redirect him to another screen that displays the details of this item. I am displaying only the number of the order and the date, once I click on it, it should show more details. How do I do that?

Here's my code so far:

```
public class Orders extends Fragment {

    private String jsonResult;

    //Here I get the order id and date
    private String url = "https://www.example.com/orders.php";
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView16);

        //Getting current date and displaying inside the textView
        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        textView3.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentDate));

        accessWebService();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                String[] parts = item.split(" ");
                String order_nbr = parts[0];
                String order_id = order_nbr.replaceAll("[#]","");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("order_id", order_id);
                System.out.println(order_id);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("order_id",MainScreen.USERID);

            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();

            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(url,data);

            jsonResult = result;

            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListDrwaer();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[] { url });
    }

    // build hash set for list view
    public void ListDrwaer() {
        List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("orders");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String order_number = jsonChildNode.optString("orderid");
                String order_dateNhour = jsonChildNode.optString("order_date");

                String[] parts = order_dateNhour.split(" ");
                String date = parts[0];
                String hour = parts[1];

                String[] test1 = date.split("-");
                String year = test1[0];
                String month = test1[1];
                String day = test1[2];


                String outPut = "#" + order_number + "         " + day+"/"+ month +"/"+ year + "         " + hour + "      >";
                employeeList.add(createEmployee("orders", outPut));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), employeeList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[]{"orders"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
        HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
        return employeeNameNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It appears that you are handling item clicks just fine in your code. You even start a new Activity when an item is clicked. So what is the issue? How is this not working for you?

Comment: Yes it is working the way it is. But I'm getting only the order id and date from the data base and displaying it in the list view. I want the get more details of the order to display it on the other screen/activity after I click on an item in the list view.

Comment: So just pass in more extras to your intent with the info that you want to provide. Still not seeing the problem here.

Comment: The data inside the ListView is one single string containing the order id, order date and hour. To pass the order id to the other activity I am doing a string.split. The problem is that the data that I also want to pass to this activity is not inside this "one single string" because I don't want to display it  in the listview. Only on the other activity.

Comment: I may be wrong but probably you can write n number of `putExtra` in intent and push whatever you wish to pass like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398668/how-to-pass-listview-selected-item-values-to-another-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem after all! I created an ArrayList of lists to store all the data I want to show in the next screen from all the orders (even though I just wanted to show in the ListView 3 values):

```
List<List<String>> order_details = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

This way list #1 would be for the first order details, #2 would be for the second order details, and it goes on. After I click on an item in this ListView I search in this ArrayList which list has this particular order number and I sent to the next activity (Order Details) all the data stored in that list regarding this particular order. It worked just fine!